# jquery set height of absolute child to the parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have absolutely positioned div inside relatively positioned parent. I want to check the outer height of a absolutely positioned child and apply it as a min-height to the parent using jquery. Divs are repeated several times on one site and this is my main problem. So far I have:

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4F7c9/)

**HTML**

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="entry-main">
        <div class="entry-meta">
            Lorem<br />
            Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="entry-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<article class="post">
        <div class="entry-main">
            <div class="entry-meta">
                Lorem<br />
                Ipsum<br />
                Dolor<br />
                Sit <br />
                Amet
            </div>
            <div class="entry-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.post').css('min-height', $('.entry-meta').outerHeight());
```

**CSS**

```
.post {
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
.entry-main {
    position: relative;
}
.entry-content {
    margin-left: 220px;
}
.entry-meta {
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The problem is that my newbie jquery code checks the height of first .entry-meta and then apply the same height to all .post articles. I want that each .entry-meta div height would be checked inside every .post article and applied accordingly:

1. Outer height of first .entry-meta = min-height of first .post
2. Outer height of second .entry-meta = min-height of second .post
3. Outer height of third .entry-meta = min-height of third .post
4. ...

Comment: this is how to do it http://jsfiddle.net/ehteshamkafeel/4F7c9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through the `.post` elements and set their min heights appropriately

```
$('.post').each(function(){
   $(this).css('min-height', $('.entry-meta', this).outerHeight());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4F7c9/2/